# Populate + Aggregate in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two Mongoose models: one for transactions and the other one for the tags associated with them. In order to implement some reports, I need aggregate code like this:

```
Transaction.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$tags' },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$tags',
      amount: {
        $sum: '$amount'
      }
    }
  }
])
```

### Question

This produces output containing `_id` and `amount`. Now, I'd like to populate the other fields (e.g. `name`) from the model, keeping the calculated `amount` column. Can I do that within a simple `populate`?

### Edit

The schemas for the models I'm describing:

```
var TransactionSchema = new Schema({
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  amount: {
    type: Number,
    required: 'Forneça um valor',
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: 'Forneça uma data',
    default: Date.now
  },
  fromOfx: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  correlated: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  tags: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'TransactionTag'
  }],
  correlates: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Transaction'
  }],
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

var TransactionTagSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Forneça um nome',
    trim: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  amount: {
    type: Number
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi can you share sample document ?

Comment: @JohnnyHK: I don't think it's the same thing, because I have the ObjectId of the field that I want to populate, but I need to still keep the `amount` field with the calculated value. I did try that snippet, but the column simply wasn't populated. This is my first big Node project, so I pretty much suck at debugging it. Is there anything I can do to diagnose why that command didn't work?

Comment: @RohitJain: edited with schema ;)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can populate an aggregation after you fetched the data from the MongoDB. This will look something like this:

```
// Your aggregate query from your question
Transaction.aggregate([{
                            $unwind: '$tags'
                        }, {
                            $group: {
                                _id: '$tags',
                                amount: {
                                    $sum: '$amount'
                                }
                            }
                        }])
    .exec(function(err, transactions) {
        // Don't forget your error handling
        // The callback with your transactions
        // Assuming you are having a Tag model
        Tag.populate(transactions, {path: '_id'}, function(err, populatedTransactions) {
            // Your populated translactions are inside populatedTransactions
        });
    });
```

Comment: Perfect! I was trying to pass populate with `{path: 'tags'}`, which, now that I think about it, makes me feel kinda silly. Just one more thing now, doing this throws my tags into the `_id` field. Is there a Mongo-y way to make them go to a `tags` attribute instead?

Comment: Ok, I just found out about [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/). Great!

Comment: Also as of 3.2 you can now use the $lookup feature to perform joins inthe aggregation pipeline - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: @cyberwombat is correct, more detail [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36021832/441930) to another similar question.