# Merge two objects in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have two models in `user.js` and `userProfile.js` of mongoose,  where I want to get documents using a join query but I have not take ***ref*** in user schema so I have code as below:

**user.js**

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
     nick_name:{type:String},
     email: {type: String},
     password: {type: String},
    is_active:{type:String,enum:['1','0'],default:"1"},
},{ collection: 'user'});
```

**userProfile.js**

```
var userProfileSchema = new Schema({
    user_id:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
    first_name:{type:String},
    last_name:{type:String},
    address:{type:String},
    country:{type:String},
    state:{type:String},
    city:{type:String},
    gender:{type:String,enum:['m','f','o'],default:"m"},
    is_active:{type:String,enum:['1','0'],default:"1"},
},{ collection: 'userProfile'});
```

**server.js**

```
app.get('/api/userLists', function(req, res) {
    User.find({},"nick_name email",function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            res.json(err);
        } else {
            var userIds = user.map(function(obj){
               return obj._id;
            });

            UserProfile.find({user_id:{$in:userIds}},function(err,userProfiles){
                if(err){
                    res.json(userProfiles);
                    console.log(userProfiles);
                }else{

                    ---------------------------------
                    -What to do here, I have no idea.-
                    ---------------------------------

                    res.json(user);
                }
            });

        }
    });

});
```

**expected output as follows**

```
{
 "nick_name"   : "laxman",
 "email"       : "laxman@mailinator.com",
 "first_name"  : "my first name",
 "last_name"   : "my last name",
 "address"     : "my address",
 "country"     : "my country",
 "state"       : "my state",
 "city"        : "my city",
 "gender"      : "m",
}

**OR**

{
 "nick_name"   : "laxman",
 "email"       : "laxman@mailinator.com",
 "profile" :{
        "first_name"  : "my first name",
        "last_name"   : "my last name",
        "address"     : "my address",
        "country"     : "my country",
        "state"       : "my state",
        "city"        : "my city",
        "gender"      : "m",
   }
}
```

**dependencies**

```
"express"  => "version": "4.7.4",
"mongoose" => "version": "4.4.5",
"mongodb"  => "version": "2.4.9",
"OS"  => "ubuntu 14.04 lts 32bit",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this one, or you could use [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to make codes more concisely.

```
MyUser.find({}, 'nick_name email', function(err, users){
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else {
        var len = users.length;
        var curIdx = 0;
        var newUsers = [];

        users.forEach(function(user) {
            UserProfile.findOne({user_id: user._id}, function(err, ret) {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);
                else{
                    // combine those two objects here...
                    user.set('profile', ret.toJSON(), {strict: false})
                    newUsers.push(user);
                    ++curIdx;

                    if (curIdx == len) {
                        //console.log(newUsers);
                        res.json(newUsers);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Population would be ideal in your case. From the **[docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)**:

> Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified
>   paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s).

Population will seamlessly help you bring data from the `Profile` collection into your `User` model. For example, to get the second output in the json form

```
{
    "nick_name": "laxman",
    "email": "laxman@mailinator.com",
    "profile": {
        "first_name"  : "my first name",
        "last_name"   : "my last name",
        "address"     : "my address",
        "country"     : "my country",
        "state"       : "my state",
        "city"        : "my city",
        "gender"      : "m",
    }
}
```

consider the following example with the approach you can take. Change your `User` schema to

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    nick_name: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    password: { type: String },
    profile: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'UserProfile' }
},{ collection: 'user'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

In your user schema definition, you add the primary surrogate key to a user profile, called `ObjectId`, referenced as `_id` in the data to get the populate functionality. This will be the key used to refer to documents in the `UserProfile` collection.

**Reading the data**

This is where Mongoose population displayes how very straightforward, easy and fast it is to makes reads of documents through its **[`populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate)** function. So for instance, to show the referenced `profile` on a user, call the **[`populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate)** method with the name of that field in a string as a parameter e.g.

```
app.get('/api/userLists', function(req, res) {
    User.find({}, "nick_name email")
        .populate("profile")
        .exec(function(err, users) {
            if(err) {
                res.json(err);
            } else {
                res.json(users)
            }
        });
```

**Writing data**

When you save data for the `user` model, you will also need to save the references to the profile. For instance, when a new `User` is created, you'll need the UserProfile _id reference saved as the profile field:

```
var user = new User();
var profileId = "54b5659536cd5250a3a93bd3"; // <-- user profile id, for example.
user.nick_name = req.body.name;
user.email = req.body.email;
user.password = encrypt(req.body.password, user.nick_name);
user.profile = profileId; 

user.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err);
    res.json({ message: 'user created!' });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for give me an idea, but in my application I have more than 15 collections related to user collection, in that situation I don't like to put all collections reference in user collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [aggreate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate-js) which implements [mongodb aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/).

Sample code may be looked like:

```
UserProfile.aggregate()
    .match({user_id: {$in: userIds}})
    .group({_id: "$user_id"})  // '$' is must
    .project(...)  // fields you want from UserProfile
    .exec(function(err, result){
        // do populate or something 
    })
```

You may also like to know [how to populate the aggregate result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680015/how-to-use-populate-and-aggregate-in-same-statement).