# How to merge 2 arrays with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Array 1** = *[X, , , , ,X]*

**Array 2** = *[ , , ,O, , ]*

I want to merge **array 1** with **array 2** to get this result: *[X, , , O, ,X]* 
instead of replacing Array 1 with array 2..

My code:

```
tictactoe.put('/updateBoard/:gameId', function (req, res) {
    Game.findOneAndUpdate({"gameId": req.params.gameId}, {
        "$set": {
           gameProgress: req.body.board
        }
    }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        return res.status(200).json(data);
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two objects in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985664/merge-two-objects-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to merge 'gameProgress' which is an array, with req.body.board which is also an array.

```
{ $addToSet: { gameProgress: { $each: req.body.board } } }
```

This will add each array element of req.body.board into gameProgress.