# Return all the elements of an array greater than a given value in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a `Content` schema. It has `course` and `content` field. `content` field has 2 sub-fields `content1` and `content2`, both of which are array of `ObjectIds`. I want to retrieve all the `ObjectIds` from `content1` which are created later than a given `ObjectId`(greater than a given `ObjectId`).

The problem is with my code, i am only getting one `ObjectId`, but i want to retrieve all the `ObjectIds` greater than `givenId`.

**My Schema is:**

```
var CurrentContentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   "course" : Number,
    "content" : {
       "content1" : [
           {
               type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
               ref : 'First'
           }
       ],
        "content2" : [
            {
                type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref : 'Second'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

**My code is:**

```
CurrentContent.find({
        'course' : givenCourse,
        'content.content1' : { $gt : givenId} 
    },{
        'course' :1,
        'content.content1.$' : 1
    }).
        exec(function(err,contents) {...
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Using `ObjectID` for representing created later is not a correct thing to do since they arn't always increasing across multiple machines. Consider adding timestamp if you need this field.

Comment: i can add that feature, but how do i get all the elements of the array that are created later that  a particular `element represented by _id` ? . `$` only gives me one array element, not multiple.

Comment: Besides that, i think `ObjectId` would work, if not i will think of something else(adding `timestamp`). But my question is how to get all the elements that matches `$gt` or `$lt` criteria, not just single one.

Answer (score 0):

`find` will just match a doc if any one of the array element in `content1` matches. It wont look further after it has matched. Hence you get only one value in `$`.

You can try this aggregation pipeline (didn't run it)

```
[
    {
        $match: {
        'course' : givenCourse,
        'content.content1' : { $gt : givenId} 
        }
    },
    {$unwind: 'content.content1'},
    {
        $match: {
        'course' : givenCourse,
        'content.content1' : { $gt : givenId} 
        }
    },
    {$project: {
        course: 1,
        content1: '$content.content1'
    }}
]
```

Comment: Will i be able to use populate after this?

Comment: I was fearing to use aggregation, as i would not be able to use populate after this. If there is any way, please tell me.

Comment: Are you using `DBRef`s? If yes you can project in whatever form, and in the callback function you can explicitly use `findOne` rather than using the mongoose populate.

Comment: Also, in `populate` you can specify the path http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680015/how-to-use-populate-and-aggregate-in-same-statement

Comment: This way i will have to do multiple `findOne`, which is not good. Using `populate` i could have got all those `documents` as a single `object`.

Comment: What about the `path` ?

Comment: i can do this using path, but will be the case when i am doing multiple findOne, which i want to avvoid somehow, if nothing comes up i will use that only as last resort.