# Trying to get data from Mongo DB with aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have "Offers" and "Requests" collections, I need to get all offers that user made, group them by requests and find the lowest "Offer.price" on each request, each offer has requestId field.
I am using aggregate to solve this,

```js
db.Offer.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      ownerId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.ownerId)
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$requestId",
      price: {
        $min: "$price"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

and This is what i get :

```js
 [ { _id: 5dc47241af1406031489c65c, price: 14 },
   { _id: 5dc47241af1406031489c653, price: 3 },
   { _id: 5dc47241af1406031489c656, price: 5 },
   { _id: 5dc8add63f73953ff408f962, price: 6 },
   { _id: 5dc8add63f73953ff408f969, price: 22 },
   { _id: 5dc47241af1406031489c658, price: 1 } ]
```

Now I want to populate these with rest of the data from "Offer"

```js
const OfferSchema = new Schema({
  requestId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Request'
  },
  ownerId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  isBest: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  isWinner: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  }
});
```

What would be best way to do something like this? 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following dataset:

```
db.dum.insert({ownerId:1, requestId:'a', price:3, createdAt:3, isWinner:true})
db.dum.insert({ownerId:1, requestId:'a', price:1, createdAt:1, isWinner:false})
db.dum.insert({ownerId:1, requestId:'a', price:2, createdAt:2, isWinner:true})
db.dum.insert({ownerId:1, requestId:'b', price:4, createdAt:2, isWinner:true})
db.dum.insert({ownerId:1, requestId:'b', price:5, createdAt:1, isWinner:false})
db.dum.insert({ownerId:2, requestId:'b', price:5, createdAt:1, isWinner:false})
```

You could use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/)

Here, for a grouping id, we keep all matching documents as an array (`candidates`).

On the `project` stage, for each group we iterate through the array, and reduce it to the minimal element found (by price that is)

```
db.dum.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      ownerId: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$requestId",
      candidates: { $push:'$$ROOT'}
    }
  },
  {
    $project:{
      item: {
        $reduce: {
          input: '$candidates',
          initialValue: '$candidates.0',
          in: { 
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $lt: ['$$value.price', '$$this.price']
              },
              then:'$$value',
              else:'$$this'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot:{newRoot:'$item'}
  }
]).toArray()
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ddcc8e0eb1f0217802fb507"),
    "ownerId" : 1,
    "requestId" : "b",
    "price" : 4,
    "createdAt" : 2,
    "isWinner" : true
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ddcc8e0eb1f0217802fb505"),
    "ownerId" : 1,
    "requestId" : "a",
    "price" : 1,
    "createdAt" : 1,
    "isWinner" : false
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfect, For anyone who has same issues I also needed to populate results with data from other collection, $lookup didnt work for me so I made another query in .then() to populate results, you can find more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680015/how-to-use-populate-and-aggregate-in-same-statement