# Filter timeperiod in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodes

model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const user = new Schema ({
id:{type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId},
firstName:{type:String, required:true},
lastName:{type:String, required:true},
pic:{type:String},
gender:{type:String},
dob:{type:String},
maritalStatus:{type:String},
nationality:{type:String, enum: ['Indian', 'Others']},
streetAddress: {type:String},
city: {type:String},
state: {type:String},
postalCode: {type:String},
country: {type:String},
phone: {type: String},
email: {type:String},
jobTitle: {type:String},
department: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'department'},
dateOfJoining: {type:String},
employeeStatus: {type:String, enum: ['Working', 'Resigined', 'Terminated']},
kra: {type:String},
assignedSupervisor: {type:String},
assignedSubordinate: {type:String},
workExperience : {type:String},
skills: {type:String},
password: {type:String, required:true},
createdOn : {type:Date, default:Date.now}  <<<<=====   filter will work on this
})

 module.exports = mongoose.model("user", user);
```

query.js

```
exports.getUser = async(userId, employeeStatus, department, firstName, timePeriod) => {
if (timePeriod) {
    if (timePeriod = 'today') {
       ====>>>>>>> I want here if req.query.timeperiod = today then it show result whose createdOn is today. createdOn is the field in user schema given above 
    }

}
let queryFilters = { employeeStatus, department, firstName, timePeriod}
queryFilters = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(queryFilters));
console.log(queryFilters)
return await model.find(queryFilters).populate("department").exec();
}
```

handler.js

```
getUser = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    let user = await userController.getUser(req.query.employeeStatus, req.query.department, req.query.firstName, req.query.timePeriod)
    req.data = user
    next()
}
catch (e) {
    req.status = 400;
    next(e)
}
}
```

Query is working fine. I want if req.query.timePeriod = today then query.js must return result whose createdOn is having today's date. createdOn is field as seen in model.js.  I have stucked here . Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the **year-month-date** does match but time when document got created & input doesn't match, So you can do it using [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/index.html) from aggregation which converts date field in DB to **"%Y-%m-%d"** format :

```
{
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $dateToString: {
              format: "%Y-%m-%d",
              date: "$createdOn"
            }
          },
          "2020-04-17" /** Input */
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5nYN1wa4tOO)

**Note :** All dates in MongoDB are stored in UTC. So, when you say **today** then the string taken out for input **"2020-04-17"** should refer to UTC. Let's say when you add a document around 11pm **CST** (Central Time in USA) on April 17th 2020 then document's `createdOn` will be April 18th as **UTC** is ahead of **CST**, Similarly when you do it from **IST** at 1am April 18th then documents `createdOn` will be April 17th cause **UTC** is behind **IST**. So in your node.js code you can do something like `new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]` to get **UTC** converted date. If you don't want these conversions maybe you can store just string like this **"2020-04-17"** in documents. If you wonder how to use `.populate` with `.aggregate()` then check this :: [how-to-use-populate-and-aggregate-in-same-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680015/how-to-use-populate-and-aggregate-in-same-statement)

Comment: It can be done using aggregate query but i have to change whole workflow. including all other filters department name, employee status. Is there any way to do it with mongoose instead of mongo

Comment: @ShubhamSharma : No as I’ve already mentioned you need to convert your date to bring existing field and input to same format(from code you can’t know exact time with seconds of createdOn’s value).. either you’ve to change your writes as you can’t do that now atleast you’ve to change your reads to use aggregation once you start changing it doesn’t take time using aggregation it’s so easy and you can easily find much help