Sort by field of an object in array where id matches the specific element object id in the array NestJS , Mongodb
I have following result data which is not properly sorted according to my needs
 [
 {
    "_id": "defmongodb_objectId",
    "categories": [
      {
        "category": "123mongodb_objectId" //reference Id
        "positionAccordingToCategory": 2,
      },
      {
        "category": "789mongodb_objectId" //reference Id
        "positionAccordingToCategory": 1,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "_id": "abcmongodb_objectId",
    "categories": [
      {
        "category": "789mongodb_objectId" //reference Id
        "positionAccordingToCategory": 2,
      },
    ],
  },
 {
    "_id": "0mongodb_objectId",
    "categories": [
      {
        "category": "789mongodb_objectId" //reference Id
        "positionAccordingToCategory": 0,
      },
    ],
  },

]
EXPECTED RESULT
   [
     
      {
        "_id": "abcmongodb_objectId",
        "categories": [
          {
            "category": "789mongodb_objectId" //reference Id
            "positionAccordingToCategory": 2,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        "_id": "defmongodb_objectId",
        "categories": [
          {
            "category": "123mongodb_objectId" //reference Id
            "positionAccordingToCategory": 2,
          },
          {
            "category": "789mongodb_objectId" //reference Id
            "positionAccordingToCategory": 1,
          },
        ],
      },
     {
    "_id": "0mongodb_objectId",
    "categories": [
      {
        "category": "789mongodb_objectId" //reference Id
        "positionAccordingToCategory": 0,
      },
    ],
  },
]

I want to sort the result by that positionAccordingToCategory which the given id matches with the category.
EXAMPLE
The id provided is 789mongodb_objectId, and it is the second element of the categories array, so I want the result by the positionAccordingToCategory of category, 789mongodb_objectId.
ISSUE
The issue is that it sorts the result by matching the **first** element of the categories array no matter what category id is provided.
Basically I want to show the same document at different positions in different categories ,according to category.
MY CURRENT QUERY
await this.myModel
      .find({
        // other filters
        categories: { $elemMatch: { category: 'category._id '} },
      })
      .sort({ 'categories.positionAccordingToCategory': -1 })

This query only works when there's only single object element in categories
It's not like query throws any error when there are more than one element, but the issue is it disturbs the order in the particular category list. As in the above example the element should be visible at 1st index but instead it goes to 2nd index, and if there are another element of that category with the same index as 2 than it moves to 3rd index
YOU CAN PROVIDE ANY AGGREGATION QUERY SOLUTION WHICH I WILL USE AT THE LAST OPTION, BUT I WON'T PREFER ANY AGGREGATION HERE.

Have you checked out $sortArray?

I did, but what about this? Can you explain how $sortArray might help?. Because I coludn't figured it out properly

$sortArray is just sorting one array of single object. You want me to bring the element upword with this beacuse query picks the first elemet..

How it will sort the actual result. The over all array result?

like this?

Check my question from top I've updated it

If what you're after is sorting the found items according to the positionAccordingToCategory of the matched array element, than no, I believe there's no way to achieve this with a query. That's exactly what aggregations are for.

@ethanfar Ok, could you provide an aggregation for that?

@ray check this https://mongoplayground.net/p/mKZpS49J5hA. Unfortunately your aggregation $sortArray giving the same result.

i do not get the question here. based on what is the order of original collection 1,2,3 become 2,1,3

@cmgchess Categories is a field of a schema, and the type is an array of category objects. Categories array can have multiple category objects. I want to sort the entire document where a given id matches with categories.category, and then use the positionAccordingToCategory value of the matched id in the sorting process, and ignore all other elements in the categories array of the object where given id matched.

@MNouman added as an answer

This is just one way to do this using an aggregation. There must be infinite possibilities, but this one's tested and it works (I've change the category ids into names, but it's the same concept).
Notice that I've added an extra first $match stage that you might not need, so feel free to remove it, and the last $project stage is just clean up, so you might be able to get rid of that one as well.

[
  {
    '$match': {
      'categories': {
        '$elemMatch': {
          'category': 'category_789'
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      '_id': 1, 
      'categories': 1, 
      'sortCategory': {
        '$filter': {
          'input': '$categories', 
          'as': 'c', 
          'cond': {
            '$eq': [
              '$$c.category', 'category_789'
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$sort': {
      'sortCategory.positionAccordingToCategory': -1
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      '_id': 1, 
      'categories': 1
    }
  }
]


With this how the population will work?As you I stated the category field is a reference, how each element of every object inside the array will be populated?

I tried with gpt, generated a similar query, worked well, but then stuck with populations..

You can easily change it back into IDs. The reason I didn't use IDs is because I didn't have the rest of your data (i.e. the Category collection) and since I tested it in MongoDB, I had to replace the fake IDs with something that won't break the test. It's exactly the same thing, but you'll just have new ObjectId('...validmongoid...') instead of 'category_789'

Yes I understand that part, but my concern was with the population as well.

If by "population" you're referring to mongoose.js populate method, it would work perfectly as long as you have a valid id and the population schema is well defined. Otherwise, I'm not sure which populate you're referring to.

You know in query you just use populate() , and it populates all the referenced ones, and in aggregation I tried with $lookup , but the results were not good and it was breaking sorting as welll.

Yes indeed mongoose.js populate I'm talknig about

Am I able to clearly explain sir?

The populate method should work without a problem. If it doesn't it has to be some other issue you have which could be with either the correlation of this category id to the actual ids in the category collection, or more likely, the mongoose schema's population properties are not defined well. Note that you have to specify in the schema which reference collection it refers to, e.g.: { ..., category: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Categories', required: 'true' }, ... }

The referenced are written ok. In a normal query find().populate({path:'category',model:MOdel}) this works good, but with aggregation .populate() not allowed. And with $loopup I'm not able to work with that

It is possible, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680015/how-to-use-populate-and-aggregate-in-same-statement

If you don't want to use the second query method, you could do it with $lookup as well. Shouldn't be a problem.

with $lookup the issue was that it was only populating the category received in the $match stage. But if there are more than 1 , like 2,3 other category elements in an array it wasn't populating those.

I have to use $lookup after $sort stage right?

I finally , adjusted that populate thing, the method with two queries were not working, than I tried with simple $lookup and It worked. Thanks a lot for your time and effort, really thanks a lot.I'll update the answe later with $lookup

@MNouman No problem, I'm glad it worked out
